# Translate combination of characters into another character (or another combination)

Tags: python, string

OK, so I got this peculiar task :)

Assume we have a `string` of characters (a word) and it needs to be translated into another string of characters.

In it's simplest form this cloud be solved by  using `string.maketrans` and `string.translate`.

However, in my case a **combination of two characters** from the first string should be translated into **another combination** or a **single character** of a result string, a **single character** could be translated into **combination of two characters** and finally a single character could be translated into single character e.g.

```
  ai -> should become e
  oi -> should become i
```

on the other hand

```
  8 -> should become th
```

but

```
  w should become o  
  y should become u
```

other characters may stay intact e.g.

```
  a should remain a
  o should remain o
```

So for the following input

```
aiakotoiwpy
```

the expected output would be

```
eakotiopu
```

One approach, I am thinking of is using hash table (for translations) and reading the input `sting` character by character and performing the replacement. I am wondering if there is any 'smarter' approach?

Any valuable input will be highly appreciated!

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Tried this (as was suggested):

```
d = {
        'ai': 'e',
        'ei': 'i',
        'oi': 'i',
        'o' : 'o',
        'a' : 'a',
        'w' : 'o',
        'y' : 'u'
    }
    s ="aiakotoiwpy"
    pattern = re.compile('|'.join(d.keys()))
    result = pattern.sub(lambda x: d[x.group()], s)
```

but the result is 
`aiakotiopu` 
not what was expected...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew tried that approach  - it is not working  it returns `aiakotiopu` for `d = {
        'ai': 'e',
        'ei': 'i',
        'oi': 'i',
        'o' : 'o',
        'a' : 'a',
        'w' : 'o',
        'y' : 'u'
    }`

Comment: It is because `join` does not keep the order.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew hmm...so what would you suggest? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Use `OrderedDict`, see [this demo](https://ideone.com/q9LYtH)

Comment: Look at the link I suggested: *Note that in this case you should sort the words descending by length if some of your dictionary entries are substrings of others.* So, the question is still a duplicate to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `|` (alternation) operator simply attempts matches from left to right.  So, if we can move the two character keys to the left of the one character keys in the alternation, things should work better.  We can do that by sorting in reverse with `len()` as our key function:

```
import re

d = {
    'ai': 'e',
    'ei': 'i',
    'oi': 'i',
    'o': 'o',
    'a': 'a',
    'w': 'o',
    'y': 'u',
}

s = "aiakotoiwpy"
pattern = re.compile('|'.join(sorted(d, key=len, reverse=True)))
result = pattern.sub(lambda x: d[x.group()], s)

print(result)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
eakotiopu
```

Comment: You can't talk about `|` being greedy or not as the term "greedy" applies to regex quantifiers, while `|` is an alternation operator. The first alternative matched makes the regex engine skip all others in Python `re`, which is a common behavior in all NFA regexes.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *in theory*: `(?p)` in [PyPi `regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) does exactly that in practice.

Comment: `|` cannot be greedy because it is a quantifier. My comment above is a purely terminological remark, no need to argue about it. Regex is not an easy thing, and sticking with the widely accepted terminology is reasonable in order to drown in this topic.

Comment: Thanks a lot, both approaches yours (cdlane)  and @WiktorStribiżew (with OrderedDict)  seems to have worked :)

Comment: I meant NOT a quantifier. I am a busy person, and I make errors when I am typing.